# Simple UICollectionView to show images behaves odd: Some Images are displayed correct, some at wrong position, some missing at all

Tags: uiimageview, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to show images in a grid on iPhone using a UICollectionView, showing 3 images a row. For a "dead simple test" (as I thought), I've added 15 JPG images to my project, so that they'll be in my bundle and I can load them simply via [UIImage imageNamed:...].

I think I've done everything correct (setting up & registering UICollectionViewCell subclass, use of UICollectionViewDataSource Protocol methods), however, the UICollectionView behaves very weird:

It shows only a few of the images in the following pattern:
First line shows image 1 & 3, second line is blank, next line like the first again (image 1 & 3 showing properly), fourth line blank, and so on...

If I push a button in my NavBar that triggers [self.collectionView reloadData], random cells appear or disappear. What drives me nuts is that it's not only an issue of images appear or not. Sometime, images also swap between the cells, i.e. they appear for a indexPath they are definitely not wired up!

Here is my code for the cell:

```
@interface AlbumCoverCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation AlbumCoverCell
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.imageView.image = nil;
}
@end
```

Part of the code for my UICollectionViewController subclass, where 'imageNames' is an NSArray holding all jpg filenames:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[AlbumCoverCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kAlbumCellID];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource Protocol methods
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.imageNames count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AlbumCoverCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kAlbumCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *imageName = [self.imageNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"CV setting image for row %d from file in bundle with name '%@'", indexPath.row, imageName);
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout Protocol methods
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

From the NSLog statement in cellForItemAtIndexPath: I can see that the method is called for all of the cells (not only the one's displayed) and that the mapping between indexPath.row and filename is correct.

Has anybody an idea what could cause this weird behavior?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the meantime, I've found the solution. It was actually a very subtle error in the implementation of my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass `AlbumCoverCell`.

The problem is that I've set the frame of the cell instance as the frame of the `UIImageView` subview instead of passing the bounds property of the cell's `contentView`!

**Here is the fix:**

```
@implementation AlbumCoverCell
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // WRONG:
        // _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        // RIGHT:
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_imageView];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    // reset image property of imageView for reuse
    self.imageView.image = nil;

    // update frame position of subviews
    self.imageView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}

...

@end
```

Comment: I made a similar mistake - thanks for posting up the solution you found!

Comment: @Tafkadasoh Thank you! It fixed my problem instantly, I was starting to hit my head against the wall..

Comment: @Tafkadasoh OMG! Thank you so so much! Fixed my problem too. It's the smallest thing, but it was such an annoying bug. Thanks once again for posting this. I really really appreciate it.

Comment: hi @Tafkadasoh can you tell me what is contentView?

Comment: By `nil`-ing image view you are defeating the while concept of reusing cells. This way `UIImageView` will always allocate itself before drawing on screen.

Comment: @totocaster The UIImageView isn't nilled, it's the image property of the UIImageView.

Comment: @Tafkadasoh - By doing nil-ing image property of UIImageView, it is not displaying the placeholder image also.!!

Comment: It worked for me, thanks! Although do you know why that makes a difference?

Comment: Good god almighty, spent 8 hours on this problem and your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Carlo The difference is in the origin of these two `CGRects`. Initializer argument `frame` has origin different from (0, 0) depending on cell location in collection view, while `contentView.bounds` has origin always at (0, 0) for any cell. I discovered it with debugging.